# TypeError: passport.SpotifyStrategy is not a constructor

Tags: node.js

halp me pls how do i import spotify passport strategy?
//
//IMPORTS :

```
import * as passport from "passport-spotify";
```

//FUNCTION :

```
passport.use(
  new passport.SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      cliendID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      UserModel.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
```

[The error..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2H3Z.png)

Comment: Please add the error in code block instead of putting the image here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-spotify/) page the syntax is this:

```
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;

new SpotifyStrategy( ... );
```

So if you want to use it you cannot use `passport.SpotifyStrategy` you should use `passport.Strategy`

Cleaner would be to use:

```
import { Strategy as SpotifyStrategy } from 'passport-spotify'
```

And then

```
new SpotifyStrategy( ... );
```

Comment: thank you, now im getting some cors error even if i set up my dashboard on spotify devs,
also set up cors options.. any clue?

Comment: I have seen that you have created one other question, so feel free to mark this question as solved. There is a gray tick